# getimagesize on alfresco image

Tags: php, alfresco

i'm working on a front display for an alfresco filled with pictures.

i'm building my pictures url like this :

http://myHost.com:8080/share/proxy/alfresco-noauth/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/bf0a8b21-b8d9-487d-a529-dee8c49d7c6f/filetitle.jpg?alf_ticket=myTicket

where myHost is the server and myTicket is the ticket generated at this url :

```
http://myHost.com:8080/alfresco/service/api/login?u=login&pw=password
```

Picture is displaying correctly with this url, but i want to use phpthumb to resize it, and when i try to use it on my picture, i get an http 500 error on the script and the following log :

```
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(http://myHost.com:8080/share/proxy/alfresco-noauth/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/bf0a8b21-b8d9-487d-a529-dee8c49d7c6f/filetitle.jpg?alf_ticket=myTicket): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Non-Autorisé
```

I shouldn't hit the authentification, since my link has a valid ticket (I don't hit authentification when i display normally my picture)

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to fetch the image from the share proxy URL, rather than the Alfresco one directly?

Comment: May not fit your use case exactly, but just in case it helps, Alfresco can generate a variety of thumbnails for your images automatically for you, you just need to configure it to do so. Then you could just select the appropriate rendition for your needs rather than resizing on the fly.

Comment: i'm totally new to Alfresco, i use this URL because its the only one i found to simply display a picture. Is it a bad practice ?

I'll look for these thumbnail configuration in Alfresco, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jeff states, Alfresco already creates thumbnails. So you can probably use:

**http://myHost.com:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/bf0a8b21-b8d9-487d-a529-dee8c49d7c6f/content/thumbnails/doclib?c=queue&ph=true&alf_ticket=myTicket**

Desc from alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.desc.xml

```
  <url>/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/content{property}/thumbnails/{thumbnailname}?c={queueforcecreate?}&amp;ph={placeholder?}</url>  
  <url>/api/path/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/content{property}/thumbnails/{thumbnailname}?c={queueforcecreate?}&amp;ph={placeholder?}</url>
  <url>/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/content{property}/thumbnails/{thumbnailname}/{filename}?c={queueforcecreate?}&amp;ph={placeholder?}</url>  
  <url>/api/path/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/content{property}/thumbnails/{thumbnailname}/{filename}?c={queueforcecreate?}&amp;ph={placeholder?}</url>
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the thumb, but looking in alfresco admin i can't manage to find where to set width/height for default thumb

Comment: The thumb is created by imagemagick. you'll need to dig in further to make the thumb as it is. Can't you just scale the thumb in your HTML file with width= and height= ?

Comment: i need to resize print visuals to a size more web friendly (810px width), but the actuals thumbnails are too small to resize them with html and get decent results

Comment: but 810px is no thumbnail :), you can do that to the actual image right?

Comment: i don't really want a thumbnail, just a resize on the pic (this resize is a security, as the client is a print advertising agency with huge size on their visuals), i'm trying to get through the thumbnail system of alfresco because i couldn't manage to do it with phpthumb, because of that 401 problem evoked earlier.

Comment: And if you directly use: http://myHost.com:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/bf0a8b21-b8d9-487d-a529-dee8c49d7c6f/filetitle.jpg?alf_ticket=myTicket

Comment: Did it with the no proxy url, thanks @Tahir Malik, i didn't get the 401!